# no encuentra la tabla?

Tags: java, sqlite

Tengo una BD en sqlite que está dentro de la carpeta del proyecto [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans).

> C:\users\usuario\documents\netbeans\carpetaproyecto

Y hago una inserción en con [java](/questions/tagged/java), tal que así

```
    //INSERTAR EN LA BASE DE DATOS ASIGNATURAS (ALTAS)
             Connection conexion;

             try
             {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");       
                conexion=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:BBDD.db");//asi se pone
                Statement stasignaturas = conexion.createStatement();
                 if(!conexion.isClosed())
                     System.out.println("conexion abierta");
                 else
                     System.out.println("conexion cerrada");



String cadenita="insert into `asignaturas` values('"+casignatura.getText()+"','"+cdpto.getText()+"','"+Integer.parseInt(caprobados.getText())+"','"+Integer.parseInt(csuspensos.getText())+"','"+Integer.parseInt(ctotal.getText())+"','"+Integer.parseInt(cporaprobados.getText())+"','"+Integer.parseInt(cporsuspensos.getText())+"');";

               stasignaturas.executeUpdate(cadenita);
              // conexion.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"registro insertado",
                         "registro insertado...",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             } 
             catch (SQLException ex) 
             {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error sentencia sql",
                         "conexión fallida...",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                       System.out.println(ex);
             }
             catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error al iniciar conexión",
                         "conexión fallida...",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             }
```

Pero me salta la **SQL Exception** diciendo: **No such table: asignaturas**
¿Porqué puede ser?

Comment: Luego que hayas obtenido la conexión a base de datos, sería bueno que cambies ese `executeUpdate` por un `PrepredStatement` donde tus sentencias pueden recibir parámetros. Esto evitará que tu aplicación sufra de SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje:

> SQL Exception diciendo: No such table: asignaturas

indica que no existe la tabla "asignaturas", asegura que realmente se encuentre dentro de tu base de datos `BBDD.db`.

Otro detalle que puede causar el problema es que no especificas el nombre del archivo de la base de datos correctamente, ya que crea una base de datos vacía y por lo tanto no existiria la tabla.

actualización: Quita las comillas simples del nombre de la tabla al construir tu querystring::

```
String cadenita="insert into asignaturas values('"+casignatura.getText()+"','"+cdpto.getText()+"','"+Integer.parseInt(caprobados.getText())+"','"+Integer.parseInt(csuspensos.getText())+"','"+Integer.parseInt(ctotal.getText())+"','"+Integer.parseInt(cporaprobados.getText())+"','"+Integer.parseInt(cporsuspensos.getText())+"');";
```

Comment: Acabo de hacer eso y sigue dando el mismo problema. La base de datos la tengo dentro de la carpeta del proyecto,entonces la ruta debería ser esta no? conexion=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:BBDD.db");

es que tengo la tabla dentro de la base de datos y de hecho inserté un registro a mano en la BBDD

Comment: Puede ser que el nombre de la bd sea incorrecto, ya revisaste que sea el nombre correcto? o que este dentro de un folder jdbc:sqlite://folder/BBDD.db  . Recuerda quitar las ' ' del nombre de la tabla en tu query.